# LibraryFind Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am trying to install  LibraryFind and i was successfull in many aspects until i reached the step where i have to run my application. 
i enter the following command and i get these results.

r

```
oot@ubuntu:/home/administrator/Desktop/trunk# ruby script/server 
=> Booting WEBrick...
=> Rails 2.2.2 application started on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server; call with --help for options
[2011-08-24 02:01:55] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-08-24 02:01:55] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16) [i686-linux]
[2011-08-24 02:01:55] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `create_listeners'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:70:in `create_listeners'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:75:in `listen'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:63:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:24:in `initialize'
    from /home/administrator/Desktop/trunk/vendor/rails/railties/lib/webrick_server.rb:56:in `new'
    from /home/administrator/Desktop/trunk/vendor/rails/railties/lib/webrick_server.rb:56:in `dispatch'
    from /home/administrator/Desktop/trunk/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:66
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/administrator/Desktop/trunk/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /home/administrator/Desktop/trunk/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/administrator/Desktop/trunk/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /home/administrator/Desktop/trunk/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:49
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

it seems im either missing a library or i am having a problem in my configurat

Comment: if this would help:
root@ubuntu:/home/administrator/Desktop/trunk# rails -v
Rails 3.0.10
root@ubuntu:/home/administrator/Desktop/trunk# gem -v
1.4.2
root@ubuntu:/home/administrator/Desktop/trunk# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another instance of webrick running of the port 3000. Use the command

```
ps aux | grep webrick
```

To verify it. And then kill it.

EDIT:

The [ps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_%28Unix%29) command shows you a list of the current running programs of your machine. Each program on a unix-like machine comes with a PID number associated with it. In your case, the other running instance has a pid = 12288. So you can use:

```
kill 12288
```

To kill the other instance of the server.

Comment: im new to linux i just wrote this command and it gave me the following:
root@ubuntu:/home/administrator/Desktop/trunk# ps aux | grep webrick
root     12288  0.0  0.0   4156   864 pts/4    S+   02:27   0:00 grep --color=auto webrick

then i retried ruby script/server and still i had the same error! 
what was i missing and what does this code exactly do
"ps aux | grep webrick" please clarify!

Comment: bash: kill: (12288) - No such process

Comment: @ghassan..try `fuser -n tcp 3000` and kill the process listed if any. Then restart the server..or u can start the server in another port `ruby script/server -p 3001`

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly now im able to at least view the software in my browser! thanks alot fellas!